# Signing an Assembly in Visual Studio Code Application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, .net-assembly, signing

I know how to signing an assembly in visual studio.But with Visual Studio Code, I couldn't have any clue,could someone explain how to signing an assembly in **Visual Studio Code**

Thanks in Advance

Jayendran